# R: summary for for ridged regression does not work in r

Tags: r, machine-learning

am trying to get model info(cofs ,p value, intercept and so on)using summary it works fine for lm but for ridged it does not work i have tried using summary and $finalmodel but it does not show any usefull info here is what it shows

```
            Length Class      Mode     
call         4     -none-     call     
actions      8     -none-     list     
allset       7     -none-     numeric  
beta.pure   56     -none-     numeric  
vn           7     -none-     character
mu           1     -none-     numeric  
normx        7     -none-     numeric  
meanx        7     -none-     numeric  
lambda       1     -none-     numeric  
L1norm       8     -none-     numeric  
penalty      8     -none-     numeric  
df           8     -none-     numeric  
Cp           8     -none-     numeric  
sigma2       1     -none-     numeric  
xNames       7     -none-     character
problemType  1     -none-     character
tuneValue    1     data.frame list     
obsLevels    1     -none-     logical  
param        1     -none-     list
```

i am using caret

Comment: What packages are you using?

Comment: i am using caret